# PHP do not show exact return value from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i dont know why i am getting and output like this "Resource id #14". Instead of showing the output.

here is how my function looks like

```
public function option_by_name($option_name=""){
        global $database;
        $sql = "select option_value from ".self::$tabel_name." where option_name='{$option_name}' and autoload=1";
        $option_value = $database->query($sql);
        echo $option_value;
    }
```

MySQL query is working fine. But there is something i am missing in PHP which is not returning the value.

One more is do `return` only output Boolean value?

Thank you!

Comment: You have too loop over the query. I don't know how your DB class looks like, but I assume it's something like `$database -> fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Yes, you're missing the fact that the return form $database->query() is a `resultset` resourse; you can iterate over that resultset to get individual results

Comment: `return` can return everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just output the query result. That is what's known as a "Resource". Instead, you must query the return and output the rows.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($option_value);
echo $row[0];
```

Try this.

Comment: Could you please mark the answer as the solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

**You are miss it**

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($option_value, MYSQLI_BOTH);

echo $row[0];
```